# Visual Studio Error finding assembily

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am receiving this error.

Unable to open module file 'C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\AssemblyInfo.vb': System Error &H80070002&    C:\Users\Matt\Desktop\AssemblyInfo.vb

When i manually put the file on the desktop it works fine.

However i don't want to keep my file on my desktop. Is there a way to change its location?

Comment: Remove it from the project then re-add it but from your preferred location?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer,
For anyone else having this trouble.

I went to Project up the top of Visual Studio and then clicked Show all Files.
On the right where my project is, I clicked the down arrow on the My Project folder
and for some reason there were 2 AssemblyInfo.vb files. The first one was linking to my desktop which was what it was looking for.

I deleted this file and it used the second one which was in My Project folder.
If you need you can also Manually create an AssemblyInfo.vb file and drag / drop it into the My Project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I got my solution like this.
Originally I had opened VS and then opened the project this resulted in the error.
To fix it.
Browse to you .sln file and double click on that.

That worked for me.